# Cannot instantiate class utils.listeners.TestListener. Empty test suite

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng, extentreports

I want to generate extent report using testng in intellij, but when I run the xml file i got this kind of error. Can anyone help me to fix this error?

[image: this is the error got]

This is TestListener class

[image: this is TestListener class]

Xml Suite

[image: this is xml file for test suite]

Comment: Please post your test code

Comment: @DeedarAliBrohi post edited. Thanks

Comment: TestListener is a abstract class it can not initiate

Comment: @DeedarAliBrohi but when I didnt declare it as abstract i got red line error

Comment: Please look on following example

https://www.guru99.com/listeners-selenium-webdriver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove abstract in TestListener Class.

You must implement all methods present ITestlistner even if you have nothing to do with that method.  In your custom listener, you have missed one method.

Add this empty method to your TestListener class

```
 @Override      
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0) {                  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

    }
```